# Split wchar_t string defined using pointer into constituent wchar_t characters in C

Tags: c, string, unicode, wchar-t

I would like to split a wchar_t string defined using pointer to its constituent wchar_t characters in C. i.e, 
if wchar_t *wcs = L"बहन" , then the output should be ब ह न

I tried the below 2 code snippets, but failed to get the desired output.

(1)

```
wchar_t *input = L"बहन";
int i=0;
while (input[i] != L'\0') {
      printf("i = %d : %lc\n",wcslen(input), input[i]);
      i++;
}
```

(2) In this approach I was not sure about what was to be used to split the string using the wcstok function. Hence, I gave the argument as L"".

```
wchar_t *input = L"बहन";
wchar_t *token;
wchar_t *state;
for (token = wcstok(input, L"", &state);token != NULL;token = wcstok(NULL, L"", &state)) {
        printf("Here %d: %s\n",wcslen(token),token);
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the `L` modifier on the `"बहन"` string?  Do you need to use `wprintf()`?

Comment: `wcslen` returns a `size_t`; you should use the `%zu` format instead of `%d` to print it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sorry, it was in the correct format. I missed it out in the snippet while I  wrote the snippet here. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MOehm: Tried %zu . But both %zu and %d are giving the same output.
And what i need more importantly is the characters to be seperated out.

Comment: What output do you get from (1)? In what way is it wrong?

Comment: @AlanStokes: The output is:
    i = 3 : ,
    i = 3 :
It didn't loop thrice, and also its not printing the characters

Comment: If this is a windows console program, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how